# The Tiger equation

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

X/2 + X = Tiger was no.1

X + a + X/2 = The Gates of Sound

X*2 reversed = Y2K

X tilted = A unique flag

x - 1 = X

What is X?

Comment: Should it be assumed that `x` and `X` are the same?

Comment: The difference is intended

Comment: Hi Enigma, good to see you back!

Comment: My gut instinct is that X is a number, but every time it's used it is broken down into some letters which add up to that number (except maybe for tilted).  But I haven't been able to make that work yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

X is

> **W** (or w)

X/2 + X =

> VW [Tiguan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volkswagen_Tiguan)

X + a + X/2 =

> WAV/wav [(a digital audio format)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV)

X*2 reversed =

> MM (roman numeral for 2000)

X tilted =

> [The flag of Nepal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Nepal), which has a unique shape (kind of like a tilted W)

x - 1 =

> 01010111 (ASCII for W), which is a 1 less than 01110111 (ASCII for w)

*or*

> w, which comes right before x in the alphabet (thanks to Marius)

Comment: `x-1` means the letter before `x`

Comment: Answer is correct, please try to elaborate on all clues...

Comment: You are missing this one "X tilted = A unique flag". This may give you a hint:  http://buyflagspoles.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/country-flags.jpg. Which one is "unique"?

Comment: @Marius: Oh, totally missed that one clue -> added. Also, the `x-1` works with both interpretations, which is quite funny. :)

Comment: What is "Tiger was no. 1" referring to...? Tiguan is not the intended answer

Comment: What does the term "Gates of Sound" refer to?

Comment: @Enigma: There's a Yu-Gi-Oh! card named "VW Tiger Catapult", but I don't see a connection to "1" or "one". WAV stores (approximated) audio wave functions, which could be seen as the "gates of sound", but I'm very uncertain about this.

Comment: Ok, maybe a bit too hard. Tiger as in Tiger Woods, hence Golf, and Gates as in Bill Gates (as wav is a Windows format)

Comment: @Enigma in this case shouldn't it be "The Sound of Gates" instead of "The Gates of Sound"?

Comment: @Marius It very well could have been. Anyway it was just a play on words...!

Comment: @Enigma How does one arrive at Tiger Woods from that clue? The interpretation in this answer makes sense, Tiger Woods less so.

Comment: Tiger (Woods) was no. 1 in Golf. Golf is also a VW-brand